# Get size of struct from pointer interface

Tags: go

I am attempting to generically get the size of any struct from an interface. This works fine with objects that are passed by value, but I can't figure out how to get the size of the object when it's passed the reference using an interface.

Here's an example indicating the problem I'm having:
https://play.golang.org/p/QXXZm-j7_hZ

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

type T struct {
    c [50]byte
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    var t T
    s := unsafe.Sizeof(t)
    fmt.Println("expected size", s)
    getSize(t, &t)
}

func getSize(valueObject interface{}, referenceObject interface{}) {
    vs := []uintptr{
        unsafe.Sizeof(valueObject),
        unsafe.Sizeof(reflect.ValueOf(valueObject)),
        reflect.TypeOf(valueObject).Size(), // THIS WORKS FOR VALUE
        reflect.TypeOf(reflect.ValueOf(valueObject)).Size(),
        0, //reflect.TypeOf(reflect.ValueOf(valueObject).Elem()).Size(), //EXCEPTION ACCESSING ELEM WITH VALUE
        0, //reflect.TypeOf(reflect.ValueOf(valueObject).Elem()).Size(), //EXCEPTION ACCESSING ELEM WITH VALUE
        0, //unsafe.Sizeof(reflect.ValueOf(valueObject).Elem()), //EXCEPTION ACCESSING ELEM WITH VALUE
        0, //unsafe.Sizeof(reflect.TypeOf(reflect.ValueOf(valueObject).Elem())), //EXCEPTION ACCESSING ELEM WITH VALUE
    }
    fmt.Println("valueObject size", vs)

    rs := []uintptr{
        unsafe.Sizeof(referenceObject),
        unsafe.Sizeof(reflect.ValueOf(referenceObject)),
        reflect.TypeOf(referenceObject).Size(),
        reflect.TypeOf(reflect.ValueOf(referenceObject)).Size(),
        reflect.TypeOf(reflect.ValueOf(referenceObject).Elem()).Size(),
        reflect.TypeOf(reflect.ValueOf(referenceObject).Elem()).Size(),
        unsafe.Sizeof(reflect.ValueOf(referenceObject).Elem()),
        unsafe.Sizeof(reflect.TypeOf(reflect.ValueOf(referenceObject).Elem())),
    }

    fmt.Println("referenceObject size", rs)
}
```

This is the output:

```
expected size 50
valueObject size [8 12 50 12 0 0 0 0]
referenceObject size [8 12 4 12 12 12 12 8]
```

As you can see, I can get the size of the object when it's passed-by-value using `reflect.TypeOf(valueObject).Size()`, but nothing gives me the correct size when I pass-by-reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no "reference" type in go, a pointer is a value like any other, and you can of course get the size of the pointer itself. You also are confusing the `reflect.Value`, the `interface{}` and the actual value you want the size of. Contributing to this confusion is that the package `unsafe` is special, and doesn't take an interface value, rather it can take any value directly, which is properly handled by the compiler.

You could handle the pointer and the struct each with a separate call, or check whether you have a pointer and call `Elem()`:

```
// struct
reflect.ValueOf(i).Type().Size()
// pointer
reflect.ValueOf(i).Elem().Type().Size()
```

However, since optionally dereferencing a pointer is quite common, you can use `reflect.Indirect` to handle both types at once:

```
reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(i)).Type().Size()
```

https://play.golang.org/p/og-uMDXCmEr

For reference, a description of what some the attempts are actually taking:

```
// size of the interface value
unsafe.Sizeof(valueObject)

// size of reflect.Value
unsafe.Sizeof(reflect.ValueOf(valueObject))

// size of the reflect.Value type 
reflect.TypeOf(reflect.ValueOf(valueObject)).Size()

// size of the interface value
unsafe.Sizeof(referenceObject)

// size of the reflect.Value
unsafe.Sizeof(reflect.ValueOf(referenceObject))

// size of the pointer value
reflect.TypeOf(referenceObject).Size()

// size of the reflect.Value type
reflect.TypeOf(reflect.ValueOf(referenceObject)).Size(),

// size of the of reflect.Value type again
reflect.TypeOf(reflect.ValueOf(referenceObject).Elem()).Size()

// size of the reflect.Value
unsafe.Sizeof(reflect.ValueOf(referenceObject).Elem()),

// size of the reflect.Type interface value
unsafe.Sizeof(reflect.TypeOf(reflect.ValueOf(referenceObject).Elem())),
```

Comment: That solved it, thanks for the detailed explanation